# Generate single-page .pdf with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I'm exporting a webpage of variable height into pdf using PhantomJS. Since pdfs can have any page size (more like ratio though, since it's vectorial), I would like to export it in a way that creates a single page in the pdf in which to fit the entire webpage.

Luckily, using the `evaluate` PhantomJS method I can easily detect the page height

```
page.includeJs('jquery.js', function() {
  var pageHeight = page.evaluate(function() {
    return $('#content').height();
  });
});
```

However, I'm not sure how I can use that to my advantage. `viewportSize` doesn't seem to affect this in any way, since I'm not rendering the viewport but the entire document. I set it to a fixed `{width: 800, height: 800}`

So I can't wrap my head around the `paperSize` sizes. Setting the height to the returned pageHeight will render 1.5x pages, so I tried tweaking the width but it doesn't really add up to any formula that I can understand.

Any ideas in how to achieve this, or do you have more insights into the correlation between the `paperSize` property and the pixel-sized bounds rendered from the page

Comment: not the focus of the question but thanks for the demoing the includeJS method to show how to get jQuery into a phantom js script!

Answer (score 3):

Extending Cybermaxs' Answer, I added

- set a fixed width (36cm corresponded well with my view port) and
- a unit to the height calculation
- set the margin to 0px.

I can't give a good explanation, but it works for me.

The full script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address, output, size;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: screenshot.js <URL> <filename>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 900};
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.includeJs("//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js", function() {
                    var size = page.evaluate(function () {
                        return {width: width = "36cm", height : $(document).height()*2+400 + "px", margin: '0px' };
                    });
                    page.paperSize = size;          
                    page.render(output);
                    phantom.exit();
                });
            }, 400);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

viewportSize simulates the size of the window like in a traditional browser. It affects the rendering of the page because of HTML layout but not directly pdf rendering.

Use [page.papersize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/paper-size.html) to define the size of the web page when rendered as a PDF. With a bit of Jquery, it's easy to render the web page in a single document, like this :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output;

if (system.args.length != 3) {
    console.log('Usage: spdf.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
        } else {
            var size = page.evaluate(function () {
                return {width: width = $(document).width(), height : $(document).height() };
            });

            page.paperSize = size;

            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried this, but for some reason my pdf will end up having 2 pages, 1 and a half being used by my page. Even the width seems like it takes up less than the viewportSize.width. It acts as if it were zoomed by some degree, but I made sure to set the zoomFactor to 1. Any idea why this would happen or how to debug what happens?

Comment: the same issue is happening to me. Any help would be appreciated